# Make Labels equal TableView Cell's Title and Subtitle

Tags: ios, uitableview, view, controller, cell

So I am just starting with coding. I have a table view where thare are cells being added to it though code. I have it so that all the TableView cells open the same view controller.

In that view controller, I have a label and a text view. What I am trying to do is whenever the user clicks on a cell, it opens the view controller and in that view controller, the label equals the cell's title, and the text view equals the cell's subtitle.

For example...

There is a cell in the table view thats says: [image: (Cell labels text)]

And the view controller it is linked to says: [image: (Detail View Controller labels text)]

But whenever a user clicks on a  different cell that has a title of *This is a title of a completely different cell* and an subtitle of *This is a subtitle of a completely different cell*

I want the view controller to update so that the Label says *This is a title of a completely different cell* and the Text View says *This is a subtitle of a completely different cell*

How can I do this to where the Label equals the cell's Title, and the Text View equals the cell's subtitle.

Thanks for the help! BTW, I'm crafting and iOS app using Xcode 8 and Swift 3

Comment: Read this article, it shows you how to make a simple master-detail app: https://www.airpair.com/swift/building-swift-app-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find the code in the master ViewController (with the tableview) that is setting the texts of the title and subtitle on the cells (in the function cellForRowAtIndexPath)
2. Pass the data values (in prepareForSegue or didSelectRowAtIndexPath) to the detail ViewController that holds the detail title and subtitle labels (make a property on the detail viewcontroller)
3. In the detail ViewController set the values of the received data values to the detail title and subtitle labels.

Try to download this example project and try to understand how it is connected
http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/ios-table-view-tutorial-using-swift

Comment: I am 100% new to coding, could you give me some code or something? :)